# SSH into Virtual Private Server connected to VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, ip

I have a VPS with Digital Ocean as well as a VPN account with Private Internet Access. I would like to be able to connect my server to a VPN in say, Switzerland, and still be able to SSH into it.

My VPS is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

#### The problem:

When I try to connect my server to the VPN, my SSH session becomes immediately unresponsive.

#### What I have tried:

Per the suggestions here: https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=8737, I have created this shell script and put it in rc.local to be run at bootup (I changed the IP address here):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo ip rule add from 111.222.333.44 table 128
sudo ip route add table 128 to 111.222.333.0 dev eth0
sudo ip route add table 128 default via 111.222.128.1
```

This script seems to work, and I have verified that it is actually being executed.

I then try to start my VPN: `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/Switzerland.ovpn &`.

I would expect this to start the VPN in the background, allowing me to continue to use my shell for other things. However, that is not what happens. Instead, I will see confirmation that the VPN has started printed to the screen, and then the session will immediately become unresponsive.

I can recover from this by restoring my Digital Ocean droplet from a backup.

#### Possible Causes:

I do not SSH over port 22, and I have blocked the port with `ufw` so maybe this is the cause of my issue. However, I did try unblocking it and switching openssl to port 22 once, and saw no change in behavior.

I could be using the wrong IP information in my script. I am fairly certain my IP address and gateway address are correct, but I am unsure how to find my subnet. I have made an educated guess based on internet research.

Perhaps Ubuntu 16.04 has changed how these things work. I have seen this done successfully on Ubuntu 12.04, and followed that model, but have things perhaps changed with newer releases?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!